# x-axis displaying incorrectly in Highcharts php

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I have the following code:

```js
  <script>
    $.getJSON('https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/ECB/RTD_M_S0_N_C_EUR1Y_E.json?start_date=2003-01-01', function(json) {
      var hiJson = json.dataset.data.map(function(d) {
        return [new Date(d[0]), d[1]]
      });
//  var hiJson = json.dataset.data.map(function(d) { 
//    return { x: new Date(d[0]), y: d[1] }; 
//     });
        // Create the chart
        $('#Euribor').highcharts('chart', {
       xAxis: {
         type: 'datetime',
   dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                     day: '%Y'
                 }  
       },   
    rangeSelector: {
     selected: 1
          },
          title: {
            text: 'Euribor Interest Rates',
          },
          series: [{
   type: 'line',
            name: 'Interest Rate',
            data: hiJson,
          }]
        });
    });
  </script>
```

This prints out a Highcharts chart, but the x-axis is incorrect. It should be in Years, but it looks more like it's a time format.

Your help is much appreciated!

R

Comment: "incorrect" based on what criteria? If you want the *dateTimeLabelFormats* property to handle it, you need to specify a value for more than just the day option. Alternatively, just use the **formatter()** function, and the **Highcharts.dateFormat()** function to return the year.

Comment: First change: `return [new Date(d[0]), d[1]]` -> `return [+new Date(d[0]), d[1]]`. That may cause a lot of troubles.

Comment: Thanks @PawełFus that's done the trick!

Comment: To explain: Highcharts require timestamp (number), not a Date object to x-values. See [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<line>.data).